# move xml namespace declarations to root element with jax-ws annotations

Tags: java, xml, soap, jax-ws, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to generate an xml payload with jax-ws and it's not working out. The server expects all namespaces to be in the envelope tag. For example:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://somewhere.namespace1.com" xmlns:ns2="http://somewhere.namespace2.com">
```

is what I need, while

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

is what I have.

jax-ws generates a payload like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:Element1 xmlns:ns1="http://somewhere.namespace1.com" xmlns:ns1="http://somewhere.namespace2.com">
            <ns2:Element2>value</ns2:Element2>
        </ns1:Element1>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but I need

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://somewhere.namespace1.com" xmlns:ns2="http://somewhere.namespace2.com">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:Element1>
            <ns2:Element2>value</ns2:Element2>
        </ns1:Element1>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have tried putting `package-info.java` files with the `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema` and I'm able to change the prefix but not move the actual namespace declaration from a child node to the root node. For example, I can (apparently?) define all the namespaces I need in the envelope with

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns = {
            @XmlNs(
                prefix = "ns1",
                namespaceURI="http://somewhere.namespace1.com"),
            @XmlNs(
                prefix = "ns2",
                namespaceURI="http://somewhere.namespace2.com"),
    }
)
```

But then in the `package-info.java` where `Element1.java` and `Element2.java` are, I don't want the namespaces defined there. I've tried

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    location = ""
)
```

but it doesn't work.

Has anyone else had a similar problem? I'm sure it's just a question of annotations but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: I am assuming that you had used "wsimport" to generate the necessary client files which would have generated interface and implementation file. Can you also share code for Java web service client that you are using to generate the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by making the call with Spring's `WebServiceTemplate#sendAndReceive(String, WebServiceMessageCallback, WebServiceMessageExtractor<T>)` where in the second parameter (the callback) I manually added the namespaces that I needed to be in the header. For example something like

```
wsResponse = this.webServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(uri,
        (webServiceMessage) -> {
            ...
            SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) webServiceMessage;
            ...
            final SoapEnvelope envelope = soapMessage.getEnvelope();
            headerNamespaces.forEach(envelope::addNamespaceDeclaration);
            ...
        }, this.responseExtractor);
```